# Delete element in Jquery if closest href has some class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu where LI sometimes have an img and sometimes not.

```
<ul id="manufact">
<li>
<a href="" class="aaa">
<img>
<span>First name</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" class="bbb">
<img>
<span>Second name</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

When there is "aaa" class in href I have to delete only first word in span. And when is "bbb" - not, but delete the img (cause in this case I don't have the real .jpg file to display, and in Safari there is a blank ugly "?").

So I try smthg like this

```
$('#manufact li > a span').each(function(){
var element = $(this);
if($(this).closest("a").is( ".aaa")){
    element.text(element.text().split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
}
// It works
else {
   Here I failed to put some JS to delete top Img.
}
});
```

My desired result is (played with closest, previous, parent etc but failed)

```
<ul id="manufact">
<li>
<a href="" class="aaa">
<img>
<span>name</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" class="bbb">
<span>Second name</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
 $('#manufact li > a span').each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if ($(this).closest("a").is(".aaa")) {
     element.text(element.text().split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
   }
   else if ($(this).closest("a").is(".bbb")) {
     $(this).prev("img").remove();
   }
 });
```

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to it to resolve your question as answered.

Comment: Cant find any checkmark( It is on question page or in list of questions in profile?

Comment: @AndrewZheludkov No worries, it's explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235  It's on the question page next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
$('#manufact li a.aaa span').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    element.text(element.text().split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
});

$('#manufact li a.bbb img').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```